# Refresh JWT expiration without refreshing or generating a new Token

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, jwt

I have an angular/.NET Core application,
I want just to refresh the expiration of the token (add 1 hour for example) without refreshing and generating a new Token.
Can i dot it or i need to generate a new Token?

This is how i'm first generating the token while authenticating to the app :

```
  var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
                {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, loginModel.UserName),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Rsa, company.Name),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.PrimarySid, company.Id.ToString()),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, ap.Language),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.IsPersistent, loginModel.RememberMe.ToString()),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Expiration, loginModel.RememberMe ? DateTime.Now.AddHours(1).ToString() : DateTime.Now.AddHours(1).ToString()),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Actor, employeeIdentifier)
            }),
            };
            foreach (string r in Role)
            {
                tokenDescriptor.Subject.AddClaims(new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, r) });
            }
            var token =
                new JwtSecurityToken(issuer: _configuration["Token:Issuer"],
                                    audience: _configuration["Token:Audience"],
                                    claims: tokenDescriptor.Subject.Claims,
                                    expires: loginModel.RememberMe ? DateTime.Now.AddHours(1) : DateTime.Now.AddHours(1),
                                    notBefore: DateTime.Now,
                                    signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["Token:Key"])),
                                    SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512));

            string tokenstring = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
            try
            {
                JwtKeys key = new JwtKeys()
                {
                    jwtKey = tokenstring,
                    userId = ap.UserName
                };
                _db.Entry(key).State = EntityState.Added;
                _db.SaveChanges();
            }
```

Any help? And Thanks

Comment: changing anything in the token effectively means to create a new one. The token is signed and any change of the payload would invalidate the signature, therefore it needs to be signed again, so best way is to work with refresh tokens.

Comment: @jps Thanks, can u give me any easy example of the implementation of refresh Token?

Answer (score 0):

After the token is generated, it can not be changed in any way. You have to generate a new token to refresh it.

A better method is that .net core send a token and expiration time (calculate the specific time, such as 10:00 add one hour, it is changed to 11:00) to angular.

When a user access the application between 10:55 and 11:00, the client can send a refresh request without signing in again. When the time exceeds 11:00, the user need to sign in again.

This is an example. Generate a deadline at the same time.

```
public IActionResult Authenticate(string username,string userpassword,string email)
    {
        var user = new Users
        {
            //...
        };
        
        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("this is a public key");
        var authTime = DateTime.Now;
        var expiresAt = authTime.AddDays(7);
        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
            {
                new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Audience,"api"),
                //...
            }),
            Expires = expiresAt,
            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
        };
        var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
        var tokenString = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

        return Ok(new
        {
            access_token = tokenString,
            expiresTime=DateTime.Now.AddHours(1)
        });
    }
```

Save the json into LocalStorage, then judge whether the expiration time is approaching when requesting.

In angualr, make the deadline minus five minutes.

```
 var deadline = (new Date(localStorage.getItem(''))).getTime();
if (deadline > (Date.now() - 60 * 60 * 1000)) {
    //refresh token
}
```

Comment: yes i want the token to get refreshed or the to add 1 hour to expiration time when the user is still activ.do you have any exmple how to do that? and thanks